# input checkbox's description click not worked on Mozilla and internet explorer 10

Tags: asp.net, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have one checkbox that checked and unchecked on description click.

My code as par below

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkId" />
<label for="chkId">Check</label>
```

It work fine with all browsers besides Mozilla (all version), when user click continue on checkbox's description (Mozilla) and on Internet Explorer 10, it work slowly, when user clicked and unchecked.   Why? This is very irritable.

Please give me solution that (checkbox) work properly on all browsers.

Please help me!

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with that at a first glance. Check that you don't have any other elements with the "chkId" id in your document.

Edit: also, are you linking any Javascript code to these elements later?. It may as well be a problem with that.

Comment: Sir, I have two control(ckeckbox and label) in my webpage, hence id not conflict another.

Comment: Is there any url where we can see the live problem?. I work in web development every day and have still to come across this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is not at all any problem, in code as per you shown here. There may be some other problem, may be you have so much add-ons in Mozilla, and so your browser become slow.

Or may be your jQuery is taking too much load.

I also facing some like this problem in my Mozila, but ignore it, because its all due to the heavily loaded Firefox a add-ons....

Comment: @NiyatiMishra That's it, If we having so much addons like, firebug, colorzilla etc and much more extension, i.e Skype click call, and so the browser become slow...
Assume that if a car having a ability to load a 5 person and we travel 8 on it, so obviously, its going to become slow

Answer (score 0):

```
Edit your code as per below.

<label for="chkId"><input type="checkbox" id="chkId" /> Check</label>
```

Comment: it not work on Mozilla. When user continue click on description for checked and unchecked.